# при изменении getting_started созданные до изменения данные должны оставаться без изменение

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
    import datetime
    from django.db import models


class Office(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bluetooth = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Currency(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    value = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    phone_id = models.IntegerField()
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    daily_salary = models.IntegerField()
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employee')
    post = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    penalty = models.IntegerField()
    getting_started = models.TimeField(default='10:00:00')
    end_workday = models.TimeField(default='19:00:00')
    deadline = models.TimeField(default='16:00:00')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name


class Attendance(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attendance', null=True, blank=True)
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='office', null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    arrival_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    care_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    lateness = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    late_penalty = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def calculate_lateness(self):
        if self.arrival_time and self.employee.start_time_default:
            start_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(self.date, self.arrival_time)
            default_start_time = datetime.datetime.combine(self.date, self.employee.start_time_default)
            if start_datetime > default_start_time:
                lateness_timedelta = start_datetime - default_start_time
                return int(lateness_timedelta.total_seconds() / 60)
        return 0

    calculate_lateness.short_description = 'Lateness (minutes)'

    def late_penalty(self):
        late = int(self.calculate_lateness())
        penalty = self.employee.penalty
        late_penalty = penalty*late
        return late_penalty

    def penalty_salary(self):
        daily_salary = self.employee.daily_salary
        penalty = self.late_penalty()
        total_salary = daily_salary - penalty
        return total_salary

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class Advance(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    advance = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

views.py

```
from .models import Attendance
from django.utils import timezone
import pytz


def start_timer(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    now = timezone.now()
    tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Bishkek')
    now = now.astimezone(tz)
    for employee in queryset:
        office = employee.office
        new_attendance = Attendance(employee=employee, office=office, date=now.date(), arrival_time=now, )
        new_attendance.save()
    modeladmin.message_user(request, f"Созданы записи Attendance для {queryset.count()} сотрудников с начальным временем.")
start_timer.short_description = "Начать отсчет времени"


def stop_timer(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    attendances = Attendance.objects.filter(id__in=queryset.values_list('id'))
    now = timezone.now()
    for attendance in attendances:
        attendance.end_time = now
        attendance.save()

    modeladmin.message_user(request, f"Время для {queryset.count()} записей было остановлено.")
```

admin.py

```
   from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Attendance, Employee, Office, Advance , Currency
from .views import start_timer, stop_timer
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.html import format_html

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Office)
admin.site.register(Currency)


class AdvanceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Advance
    extra = 00


@admin.register(Employee)
class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AdvanceInline]
    actions = [ start_timer, stop_timer, ]
    list_display = ['employee_link',  'salary', 'daily_salary', 'office', 'post',]

    def employee_link(self, obj):
        url = reverse('admin:worktime_attendance_changelist') + f'?employee__id__exact={obj.id}'
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', url, obj.first_name)


#
@admin.register(Attendance)
class AttendanceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['employee_link', 'office', 'employee_daily_salary', 'date', 'arrival_time', 'care_time', 'calculate_lateness', 'late_penalty', 'penalty_salary', ]
    list_filter = ('date',)


    def employee_link(self, obj):
        url = reverse('admin:worktime_employee_change', args=[obj.employee.id])
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>', url, obj.employee.first_name)


    def employee_daily_salary(self, obj):
        return obj.employee.daily_salary

    def employee_name(self, obj):
        return obj.employee.first_name
```